# How Can i make a table section hidden and display after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is what i am doing.. its categorized table where when clicked to button shows detail regarding otherwise remain hidden, CSS is working good for me, problem is when i click on button to display tbody nothing happens, can't get what's wrong with it. have a look on my code..

css for make him hidden unless he is not clicked,

```
   .down1 {
        display: none;
    }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show1").click(function(){
        $(".down1").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<table align="center" cellpadding="10" width="300">
    <tr>
        <th bgcolor="brown"></th>
        <th bgcolor="brown">Day</th>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="lightgrey">
            <input type="button" value="+" id="show1" />
        </td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="lightgrey">Monday</td>
        <tbody class="down1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>9:00 -10:00 (time) </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>9:00 -10:00 (time)</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
       <td>9:00 -10:00 (time)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>9:00 -10:00 (time)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>9:00 -10:00 (time)</td>
    </tbody>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You have to correct: `.down { display:none; }` to `.down1 { display:none; }`

Comment: sorry my mistake it is `.down1` css is working good, jquery isn't working

Comment: There are a *lot* of syntax issues with your HTML; unclosed `tr`, as well as incorrectly placed `tr` and `tbody`.

Comment: Yes surely they are the errors , i will fix it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example can help you : [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld5dw9zf/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show1").click(function(){
    $(".down1").toggle();
    if ($(this).val() == '+') {
      $(this).val('-');
    } else $(this).val('+');
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but is this what you want?

JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yoy5xph3/1/

```
$(".down1").toggle();

$("#show1").click(function(){
    $(".down1").toggle();
});
```

I removed the css and toggled the .down1 at the start so it hides.

Comment: Yes this is what i want

Answer (score 1):

You can show my [DEMO CODE](http://jsbin.com/pehisu/3/edit)

It's working

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#show1").click(function(){
        $(".down1").toggle();
        if ($(this).val() == '+') {
          $(this).val('-');
       } else $(this).val('+');
   });
});
```

**Markup**

```
<tbody class="down1">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>9:00 -10:00 (time) </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>9:00 -10:00 (time) </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>9:00 -10:00 (time) </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>9:00 -10:00 (time) </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>9:00 -10:00 (time) </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yes same what i am trying to do